# Creating a chat event as a room owner of a site's main chat - should it show up on Community Events?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, room-owner, chat-event, community-events

I created a [chat event for space.stackexchange](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9682/the-pod-bay?tab=schedule) in its main chat room. It happens tomorrow so it should show up in the [sidebar of the main site](https://space.stackexchange.com/) already, but it doesn't. It's been an hour now so I'm wondering if this is an issue, or if it has to do with the fact I'm not a moderator. I was a moderator until recently and I vaguely recall that when I scheduled things a notice would show up that because I'm a moderator the event would automatically be added to the Community Event schedule - I can't quite remember.

Does it not show up because I'm not a mod, or is it a bug?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296600/155668

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That only happens if you're a moderator. (there's kind of a long history there, but it's mostly irrelevant so I'll skip it)

As a general strategy, if you're creating an event in chat *that would be relevant to many / most users on the main site,* either create a meta post associated with it or ask a moderator to manually add a corresponding event on the main site.

Comment: That being the case, it would be really nice if there was a button that a local mod could promote said event to be displayed on the main site as a community event...

Comment: Yeah, that would be a convenience. Post a feature-request; likely won't get done any time soon, but might motivate someone to create a userscript.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296600/155668

Comment: Huh, I didn't see the "1 new answer" thing come up before posting mine. Am I just blind, or did you use CM magic to change the date stamp on yours? :-P

Comment: You were too busy collecting screenshots... (Less than a minute apart; if you weren't watching for it the little notification is easy to miss)

Comment: I can confirm that Shog's answer did, in fact, come in first.

Comment: "That only happens if you're a moderator" - thougt you said you had to manually add event here for the Town Hall? So is it bugged?

Comment: Yeah, does appear to be broken @ShadowWizard

Answer (score 2):

### As a room owner, no. Only as a local mod.

This is what I see when creating an event for a chatroom associated with the site where I mod (any chatroom, not just the 'main' one, which I'm not even sure is well-defined for all sites):

[image: mod view]

And this is what I see when creating an event for the main chatroom for a site where I'm not a mod but am a room owner for that chatroom:

[image: RO view]