# Make a chat room event a community event

Tags: feature-request, moderators, community-bulletin, chat-event, community-events

There are occasions where a chat event could be a good community event. It would be nice if there was an easy way to allow an event from a user to be made a community event by a single button pushed by a moderator, instead of the current copy/paste method that would be required. Any chance of getting such a button added?